# XML parsing gives me empty values

Tags: python, xml, minidom

Having trouble getting this to work. What's strange is that I have 10 bookmarks in Delicious and it prints out 10 blank strings so it must be close to working.

```
import urllib
from xml.dom.minidom import parse

FEED = 'http://feeds.delicious.com/v2/rss/migrantgeek'

dom = parse(urllib.urlopen(FEED))

for item in dom.getElementsByTagName('item'):
    print item.getAttribute('title')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Title isn't an attribute, it's another tag within item.